# Markdown scripting is hanging my browser

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown

I've been having problems with threads that contain a fair amount of code, marked with the "Code sample" feature.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551125/i-have-a-win32-windows-application-and-want-to-capture-full-screen-and-remove-the) is a good example.  Opening the thread hangs my browser, Firefox 3.6, for many seconds.  In extreme cases, it trips a timeout error that lets me abort the script.

Not exactly sure when this started, it has however been very noticeable in the past few days.  Responding to such a thread is very difficult too, if I post a code sample myself then the browser goes catatonic again, often multiple times.

Comment: possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29278/browers-hangs-for-super-user-question or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38243/markdown-rendering-has-become-very-slow-recently

Comment: No-repro with WinXP FF 3.6.2 -- upgrade to the latest revision?

Comment: I have encountered this previously on Win7 with FF 3.6.1 on some of the popular questions with tons of coded answers. (Like the code golf questions with at least one code block per question, usually at least 10 lines). I cannot, however, cause it to happen with the link provided as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Firefox 3.6.2 and I did not experience this when I clicked on the provided link.

Comment: Same here, but I have experienced Firefox freezing on older machines when a lot of Javascript was in play.

Comment: Thanks, you made me look 3 feet in front of the monitor.  Reboot fixed it :(